# NameError: name is 'x' not defined when run a sample template system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the following code for a template system, which comes "Beginning Python: From Novice to Professional", 3Ed by Magnus Lie Hetland:

```
# template.py

import fileinput, re

field_pat = re.compile(r'\[(.+?)\]')

scope = {}
def replacement(match):
    code = match.group(1)
    try:
        return str(eval(code, scope))
    except SyntaxError:
        return ''

lines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    lines.append(line)
text = ''.join(lines)

print(field_pat.sub(replacement, text))
```

The book describes this text file, named `number.txt`:

```
[x = 2]
[y = 3]
The sum of [x] and [y] is [x + y].
```

When I tried to replace x & y with numbers using the template,

```
> python template.py number.txt
```

I was expecting to see `The sum of 2 and 3 is 5.` Instead, however, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\template.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(field_pat.sub(replacement, text))
  File "D:\Python\template.py", line 9, in replacement
    return str(eval(code, scope))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why does this occur? I am using Python 3.10.0, if it matters.

Comment: Your attempt to call `eval()` on `x = 2` (and likewise for `y`) is failing; that's a *statement*, not an expression, so `exec()` would be required.  Your `try`/`except` is covering up the resulting error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question a bit to meet the guidelines in [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question - please review in order to understand how we prefer questions to look here.

Comment: Oh yeah, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour].

Comment: Also: please note that [you are expected to attempt some research before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For example, here: what is your understanding of how the code is supposed to work? In particular, what does the `eval` function do? What did you learn when you read about it in the documentation? Do you expect the `except SyntaxError:` block to occur on this input? Why or why not? Did you test whether it happened? Did it?

Comment: Anyway: I've never heard of this book, but based on the code example, I'm not particularly impressed. A "template system" *shouldn't* have this kind of power in the first place, so right off the bat the design of the project is terrible guidance for anyone aiming to reach "professional". Second, when I [search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Beginning+Python%3A+From+Novice+to+Professional%22%2C+3Ed) the book title, I see a bunch of websites with sketchy domain names and URLs that are just domain.com/full-title-of-book - looks like some really aggressive SEO optimization effort.

Comment: @Karl If you remove the `3Ed`, you get [better results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Beginning+Python%3A+From+Novice+to+Professional%22&ia=web), like Amazon and Google Books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) only works on [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression), but assignment is a statement in Python. [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) works on statements.

So what you could do is try parsing an expression, then fall back to a statement.

```
def replacement(match):
    code = match.group(1)
    try:
        return str(eval(code, scope))  # Try evaluating expression
    except SyntaxError:
        exec(code, scope)  # Execute statement
        return ''
```

```
>>> text = '[x = 2][y = 3]The sum of [x] and [y] is [x + y].'
>>> field_pat.sub(replacement, text)
'The sum of 2 and 3 is 5.'
```

To be clear, any assignments will be made to `scope`, which is acting as the global scope.

---

By the way, if your input is untrusted, [`eval()` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and by extension, so is `exec()`. I hope you're only using this code for learning purposes.